# I sent my bitcoin to my own email adress instead of to my wallet, Now what?

Tags: coinbase.com

I sent my bitcoin to my own email address instead of to my wallet, Now what? I tried to send it fromcoin base to blockchain  instead I sent it to my email address I don't know how to get it to my blockcain wallet from my email

Comment: Is it the same email you used to register your coinbase account?

Comment: Can yo explain what you mean by "sent it to my email adress"? You can't send Bitcoins to an email adress. That's against the bitcoin protocol.

Comment: Also for future probably test send neglible amount when ever possible to rule out chances of loss due to human error.

Answer (score 1):

The bitcoin protocol does not support sending Bitcoins to an email address, so I am assuming that Coinbase offers a Paypal-like service that allows sending Bitcoin to family and friends' accounts with their email address. Check the inbox of the email address that you put on there for instructions on how to redeem those Bitcoins at Coinbase, otherwise, contact their support.